# jpa hibernate ambiguous issue

Tags: hibernate, jpa

the pseudo-entity classes are:

```
Member {
    id: Integer,
    startdate: Date,
    ....
}

Lecture {
    id: Integer,
    member_id: Integer(FK: Member.id),
    ....
}

Participation {
    id: Integer,
    lecture_id: Integer(FK: Lecture.id),
    member_id: Integer(FK: Member.id),
    status: Integer,
    ....
}
```

I pick up the Participation tuple by its id:

```
...
Participation participation = participationRepository.findById(id).get();
...
```

and i change the status value and save it.

```
...
participation.updateStatus(2);
participationRepository.save(participation)
...
```

but something goes wrong.

```
Error: 1052-23000: Column 'startdate' in field list is ambiguous
```

I think the hibernate print a wrong sql. How can I fix it?

```
Hibernate:
    select
        lecture0_.id as id1_4_0_,
        lecture0_.address as address2_4_0_,
        lecture0_.description as descript3_4_0_,
        lecture0_.enddate as enddate4_4_0_,
        lecture0_.latitude as latitude5_4_0_,
        lecture0_.longitude as longitud6_4_0_,
        lecture0_.member_id as member_11_4_0_,
        lecture0_.name as name7_4_0_,
        lecture0_.startdate as startdat8_4_0_,
        lecture0_.studentlimit as studentl9_4_0_,
        lecture0_.teacherlimit as teacher10_4_0_,
        member1_.id as id1_6_1_,
        member1_.address as address2_6_1_,
        member1_.career as career3_6_1_,
        member1_.latitude as latitude4_6_1_,
        member1_.longitude as longitud5_6_1_,
        member1_.name as name6_6_1_,
        member1_.password as password7_6_1_,
        member1_.phone as phone8_6_1_,
        member1_.startdate as startdat9_6_1_,
        member1_.username as usernam10_6_1_
    from
        lecture lecture0_
    left outer join
        member member1_
            on lecture0_.member_id=member1_.id
    where
        lecture0_.id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        lecture0_.id as id1_4_,
        lecture0_.address as address2_4_,
        lecture0_.description as descript3_4_,
        lecture0_.enddate as enddate4_4_,
        lecture0_.latitude as latitude5_4_,
        lecture0_.longitude as longitud6_4_,
        lecture0_.member_id as member_11_4_,
        lecture0_.name as name7_4_,
        lecture0_.startdate as startdat8_4_,
        lecture0_.studentlimit as studentl9_4_,
        lecture0_.teacherlimit as teacher10_4_
    from
        lecture lecture0_
    where
        lecture0_.member_id=?
Hibernate:
    select
        participat0_.id as id1_9_,
        participat0_.kind as kind2_9_,
        participat0_.lecture_id as lecture_5_9_,
        participat0_.member_id as member_i6_9_,
        participat0_.startdatetime as startdat3_9_,
        participat0_.status as status4_9_
    from
        participation participat0_
    where
        participat0_.lecture_id=?
Hibernate:
    select
        member0_.id as id1_6_0_,
        member0_.address as address2_6_0_,
        member0_.career as career3_6_0_,
        member0_.latitude as latitude4_6_0_,
        member0_.longitude as longitud5_6_0_,
        member0_.name as name6_6_0_,
        member0_.password as password7_6_0_,
        member0_.phone as phone8_6_0_,
        member0_.startdate as startdat9_6_0_,
        member0_.username as usernam10_6_0_
    from
        member member0_
    where
        member0_.id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        participat0_.id as id1_9_0_,
        participat0_.kind as kind2_9_0_,
        participat0_.lecture_id as lecture_5_9_0_,
        participat0_.member_id as member_i6_9_0_,
        participat0_.startdatetime as startdat3_9_0_,
        participat0_.status as status4_9_0_,
        lecture1_.id as id1_4_1_,
        lecture1_.address as address2_4_1_,
    left outer join
        lecture lecture1_
            on participat0_.lecture_id=lecture1_.id
    left outer join
        member member2_
            on lecture1_.member_id=member2_.id
    left outer join
        member member3_
            on participat0_.member_id=member3_.id
    where
        participat0_.id=?
Hibernate: 
    update
        participation 
    set
        kind=?,
        lecture_id=?,
        member_id=?,
        startdatetime=?,
        status=? 
    where
        id=?
2022-07-25 19:57:58.572  WARN 12584 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.m.jdbc.message.server.ErrorPacket      : Error: 1052-23000: Column 'startdate' in field list is ambiguous
2022-07-25 19:57:58.574  WARN 12584 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1052, SQLState: 23000
2022-07-25 19:57:58.574 ERROR 12584 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : (conn=927) Column 'startdate' in field list is ambiguous
2022-07-25 19:57:58.574  INFO 12584 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
```

Comment: The Pseudo model doesn't match the SQL selects - Lecture and Member have a 'startdate', but participation that you are updating doesn't. Either your Error is not a result of the Update SQL statement shown (some other statement maybe?) or maybe you have some Database trigger happening on Participation updates?

Comment: @Chris as you say i check the trigger i made.... and finally solve it. thanks